# What is the difference between @JsonIgnore and @JsonIgnoreProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jackson, spring-data

I need to understand the main difference between this two annotations: `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties` in Spring Boot.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JsonIgnore is to ignore fields used at field level. while,

@JsonIgnoreProperties is used at class level, used for ignoring a list of fields.

Refer [here](https://www.concretepage.com/jackson-api/jackson-jsonignore-jsonignoreproperties-and-jsonignoretype) for more info

Comment: Annotation can be applied both to classes and to properties. If used for both, actual set will be union of all ignorals: that is, you can only add properties to ignore, not remove or override. So you can not remove properties to ignore using per-property annotation.
Its clearly written in the documentation.